# Anti-ghosting (NKRO over USB) keyboard

Tags: usb, keyboard

I've recently bought a new keyboard and was surprised to find that it didn't work in Linux.

This keyboard does strange things to handle multiple key presses (anti-ghosting, a/k/a N-key rollover) over a USB interface. While I can disable this behaviour by pressing ctrl+alt+shift+N, this is bit annoying.

I've written up a [lot more detail here](http://symcbean.blogspot.co.uk/2013/05/keyboard-still-not-detected-press-f1-to.html).

I've since procured a USB to PS2 adapter - which doesn't work at all (in BIOS or in Linux). I suspect it may be faulty but don't want to spend time and effort (possibly money) trying to get a hacked solution to work.

That it works in the BIOS and in Windows without any custom drivers makes me think that Linux is just trying to be too smart about recognizing the device.

Does anybody know if support for such devices exists in recent kernels?

I believe that recent kernels allow for configuration of USB quirks at runtime - I suspect there may some mileage in trying that - but from which version? Anybody know where I can find some definitive docs on this?

(I suspect that [this hack](http://forums.opensuse.org/english/get-technical-help-here/hardware/473200-usb-gaming-mouse-04d9-a078-not-working-linux-plus-workaround.html) addresses the same underlying issue)

Comment: Is this still a problem with 2019 kernels? OP, can you update your post?

Comment: I got fed up and bought a good keyboard - https://symcbean.blogspot.com/2016/12/keyboard-nirvana-almost.html